VS code extension that uses OpenAI API doens't work
I want to write a simple VS Code extension that calls OpenAI API and tells the user the day in Danish.
I cannot find the extension when searching for it in the Extension Development Host window (after pressing F5). What could I be doing wrong ?
extension.js
const vscode = require('vscode');
import { OpenAI } from 'openai';
require("dotenv").config(); // Load environment variables from .env file

// Initialize the OpenAI client
const client = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
});


// Activate the extension
function activate(context) {
    console.log('Your extension "gpt-danish-day" is now active!');

    // Register the command
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('gpt-danish-day.getDay', async () => {
        // Call the OpenAI function to get the day in Danish
        const response = await getDayInDanish();

        // Show the result in a VS Code information message
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Today in Danish: ${response}`);
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}


// Function to fetch the current day in Danish
async function getDayInDanish() {
    try {
        const chatCompletion = await client.chat.completions.create({
            model: "gpt-4o-mini",
            messages: [
                { role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." },
                { role: "user", content: "Tell me what day is it today in Danish?" }
            ]
        });

        // Extract and return the content of the first choice
        return chatCompletion.choices[0].message.content.trim();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error calling OpenAI API:", error.message);
        return "Error fetching the day in Danish.";
    }
}


// Deactivate the extension
function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
};

package.json
{
  "name": "code-commenter",
  "displayName": "Code Commenter",
  "description": "A VS Code extension that uses ChatGPT to add comments to your code.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.80.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "gpt-danish-day.getDay",
            "title": "Get Day in Danish"
        }
    ]
},  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "vsce package",
    "test": "node ./test/runTest.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "vscode": "^1.80.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}

